# Woocommerce products not being displayed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce Woodmart theme for an online shop, we have a lot of different products but despite correct settings and ERP software some items are not displayed at all. Mostly its the case when I open the shop and it says 20 Items are being displayed but in fact only 16 I see on the product page and they are cutted off as well like this
[image: woocommerce shop]

The same problem occurs when I say 23 Items should be displayed but actually it shows less and cuts off the items again. When I choose category not all items are being displayed despite the fact that those can be found on search. Where can I find respective file for woocommerce responsible for showing items and how can I eventually fix the issue? I tried to deactivate some plugins but it didnt help out.

Comment: This is probably problem for post per page go to settings and look their may b an option how many products you want to show.

Comment: I found the error, it was some kind of event in the front-end

Comment: nice to hear it worked you can make this problem solved.